# If Else if Function does not what I want (R)

Tags: r, function, time-series

My problem is I think simple. The function does not calculate the seasonal amount of a Time Series. I do not see what exactly wrong is. I tried many things, but nothing worked.

```
ma_function_try<-function(data_set, ma_q = NULL, seasonal = FALSE, seasonal_time = NULL) {
  time_series<-data_set
  if(ma_q) {
    time_series<-ma.filter(time_series, q = ma_q, plot = TRUE)
    return(time_series)
    }
  else if (seasonal && ma_q) {
    time_series<-ma.filter(time_series, q = ma_q, seasonal = TRUE, period = seasonal_time ,plot = TRUE)
    return(time_series)

  }
}
```

Thank you and best regards

Comment: you don't need multiple returns. please add a reprex

Comment: ppl can better help if you provide reproducible data, say what you need to do, say what you want to get, and say what you have tried so far.

Comment: The second condition will never be TRUE if the first condition is FALSE. Also, `NULL` is a bad default, you should use a logical value as default.

Comment: Agreeing with my pre-commenters, but adding this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Roland Why should I not use NULL?  I dont get it.

Comment: Because logical comparison with NULL needs to use is.null instead of ==.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your fast reponse.

Lets say I have a TS like:

```
set.seed(12234)
time_series_sample<-rnorm(100,0,5)
```

I found a solution (but maybe there is a better one):

```
ma_function_test<-function(data_set, ma_q = FALSE, seasonal = FALSE, seasonal_time = FALSE) {
  time_series<-data_set
  if(seasonal == FALSE) {
    time_series<-ma.filter(time_series, q = ma_q, plot = TRUE)
    }
  else if (seasonal ==TRUE) {
    time_series<-ma.filter(time_series, q = ma_q, seasonal = TRUE, period = seasonal_time ,plot = TRUE)
  }
  return(time_series)
}
```

`